# 20 balls are put into 10 boxes, let $X$ be the random variable that accounts for the number of empty boxes. Find $EX$ and $DX$-variance.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

What I don't know how to do: Put this into a mathematical model effieciently, I honestly do not know where to start here, I've done problems with balls going into boxes and to find lets say the probability that no box is empty , but this problem is a little harder..

Comment: The usual approach is to let $X_i=1$ if Box $i$ is empty, and $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then $X=X_1+\cdots+X_{10}$ and by the linearity of expectation $E(X)=\sum E(X_i)=10E(X_1)$. For $E(X_1)$ find $\Pr(X_1=1)$. The variance is more complicated, it is $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$. To find $E(X^2)$ expand $(X_1+\cdots+X_{10})^2$. This problem has been on MSE before, and I have answered it, but probably cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

For $i=1,\dots,10$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if box $i$ stays empty and let it take value $0$ otherwise. Then:$$X:=X_1+\cdots+X_{10}$$ is the total number of empty boxes. Use linearity of expectation to find the expectation of $X$.

When it comes to the variance realize that $$X^2=\sum_{i=1}^{10}\sum_{j=1}^{10}X_iX_j$$ 
and again use linearity of expectation to find $\mathbb EX^2$.

---

**Edit**:

$\mathbb EX_i=1\mathbb P(X_i=1)+0\mathbb P(X_i=0)=\mathbb P(X_i=1)$.

$X_i^2=X_i$ so that $\mathbb EX_i^2=\mathbb EX_i=\mathbb P(X_i=1)$

If $i\neq j$ then $X_iX_j$ is Bernouilli distributed and $\mathbb EX_iX_j=\mathbb P(X_iX_j=1)=\mathbb P(X_i=X_j=1)$.

So find $\mathbb P(X_i=1)$ and $\mathbb P(X_i=X_j=1)$ for $i\neq j$.

Finally $\text{Var}X=\mathbb EX^2-(\mathbb EX)^2$

Comment: Can you maybe go into a little more detail with variance here?

Comment: There are only 10 boxes, not 20..

Comment: @JindraHelcl Thank you! I repaired.